# How to cast elements of array in kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I have column with array type where values are integers but wrapped as strings. How can i convert this column into array type with values as proper integers

Input :

Column1

["1","2","3"]

Desired output

Column1

[1,2,3]

PS : I see i can do it using mv-expand operator and then use make_list with aggregation function, but i see it is causing lot of perf over-head and there are multiple other columns in my table which needs to be taken care with aggregation differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can:

1. leave it as strings, depending on how you consume this array later on. or,
2. reformat the data at its source, before you ingest it into Kusto. or,
3. use `mv-apply` for the conversion at query runtime (can also be done at ingestion time, using an `update policy`):

```
print Column1 = dynamic(["1","2","3"])
| mv-apply Column1 on (
    summarize Column1 = make_list(toint(Column1))
)
```

| Column1 |
| --- |
| [ 1, 2, 3 ] |